# Controlling spacing in environments

Tags: spacing, cv

I'm trying to make my template for resume that requires packing much content into a page or two.

I found some environments for shaded color box and ruled section.

```
\newlist{experience}{description}{1}
\setlist[experience]{labelwidth=4em, align=left}

\newenvironment{zero_experience}{
\begin{experience}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}}{\end{experience}
}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{.95}
\setlength{\FrameSep}{0pt}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
```

To be used such as

```
\section{Education}

\begin{shaded}
    \begin{zero_experience}
    \item[\ School] University of A at B \hfill B, CA (Jan. 2013 --- Aug. 2016) \mbox{\hspace*{.5em}}
    \item[\ Degree] \textbf{ABC. Physics}
    \end{zero_experience}
\end{shaded}

\begin{experience}[leftmargin=\dimexpr\FrameRule+4em+\labelsep]
    \item[]  Research on Software Engineering and its application to Research on Software Engineering and its application to Research on Software Engineering and its application to
\end{experience}
```

However, the results show too much space

1. between the section line and shaded box.
2. the upper space in the shaded box.
3. the lower space in the shaded box.
4. between the shaded box and experience environment.

I could use `\vspace` to control the space, but I found it doesn't work all the times. So, I need to update the setup to control the spaces. How can I do that?

[image]

This is source tex code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, final]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\usepackage{framed}% http://ctan.org/pkg/framed
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[textwidth=18cm, textheight=25cm]{geometry}

\newlist{experience}{description}{1}
\setlist[experience]{labelwidth=4em, align=left}

\newenvironment{zero_experience}{
\begin{experience}
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
    }{\end{experience}
}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{.95}
\setlength{\FrameSep}{0pt}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}

    \section{Education}

    \begin{shaded}
        \begin{zero_experience}
        \item[\ School] University of A at B \hfill B, CA (Jan. 2013 --- Aug. 2016) \mbox{\hspace*{.5em}}
        \item[\ Degree] \textbf{ABC. Physics}
        \end{zero_experience}
    \end{shaded}

    \begin{experience}[leftmargin=\dimexpr\FrameRule+4em+\labelsep]
        \item[]  Research on Software Engineering and its application to Research on Software Engineering and its application to Research on Software Engineering and its application to
    \end{experience}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are using `\setlength{itemsep}{0pt}` directly. `enumitem` offers options for this. The spacing in the shaded box can be reduced with `topsep=0pt`. And `titlesec` and `KOMA` ... sigh.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all ... `titlesec` and `KOMA` ... sigh...

Now, the spacings can be controlled by `topsep` setting to the `enumitem` list and the `\OuterFrameSep` value of `framed` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, final]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\usepackage{framed}% http://ctan.org/pkg/framed
\usepackage[textwidth=18cm, textheight=25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\newlist{experience}{description}{1}
\setlist[experience]{labelwidth=4em, align=left}

\newenvironment{zero_experience}{%
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
  \begin{experience}[itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,topsep=0pt]
  }{\end{experience}
}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{.95}
\setlength{\FrameSep}{0pt}
\setlength{\OuterFrameSep}{1pt}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\section{Education}

\begin{shaded}
  \begin{zero_experience}
  \item[\ School] University of A at B \hfill B, CA (Jan. 2013 --- Aug. 2016) \mbox{\hspace*{.5em}}
  \item[\ Degree] \textbf{ABC. Physics}
  \end{zero_experience}
\end{shaded}

\begin{experience}[leftmargin=\dimexpr\FrameRule+4em+\labelsep]
\item[]  Research on Software Engineering and its application to Research on Software Engineering and its application to Research on Software Engineering and its application to
\end{experience}


\end{document}
```

[image]